# Convert Latex table into Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable, latex

Using the entire Latex file, we want to extract all the table(s) present in it and convert it into Python Pandas Dataframe and then later convert the entire table(s) in .CSV file.
The Latex files are some .pdf file research papers which have been imported in Python and converted into Tex/Latex format, which has tables present in it (The format of the table may vary). But it would be very helpful, to get a kickstart.

Importing of the Pdf files in python and converting into a latex format has been tried, the later part is not feasible right now which we have been trying. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: If you need to only do this once, consider using some OCR software to quickly convert the tables to a more easily parseable form. There are quite a few ways to make a table in latex so attempting to parse it with Python might not be the optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the .tex LaTeX code, than converting Latex tables to .csv would be just replacing of some characters `&` by `,` etc.

If the task is extracting data from a LaTeX-generated PDF file, than I suggest trying PDF to HTML converters to convert the tables in a format that you can parse in Python.